# Problems with MultiClient - server in Java

Tags: java, sockets, connection, client-server, inputstream

i'm developing a Java App, but i have a big problem. I'm trying to develop a client-server app, so that the client could retrieve information managed by a server.

The problem is that, when the connection is established, probably goes in loop, near two specifics lines of code (cause if i delete this lines, it goes on):

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

I'm an University Student and the client.java has been delivered by professor, so i do not think that this could have problem, but you never know. Now i post 3 files:

**MultiServer**: used to manage multiclients connection
**ServerOneClient**: to implements the protocol
**Client**.java

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Client;

public class MultiServer {
    
    private int PORT = 2025;
    
    private void run() throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        BufferedReader in=null;
        PrintWriter out=null;
        
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
            
            //stream di input
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            
            //creazione stream di output
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            out = new PrintWriter(bw, true);
            
            //ciclo di ricezione dal client e invio risposta
            while(true)
            {
                String str = in.readLine();
                if(str.equals("END")) break;
                System.out.println("Echoing: " + str);
                out.println(str);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Accept failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        //chiusura di stream e socket
        System.out.println("Echoserver: closing..");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
        
    }

    public MultiServer(int port) throws IOException {
        PORT=port;
        run();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        MultiServer s = new MultiServer(2025);
        s.run();
    }   



}
```

**ServerOneClient.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerOneClient extends Thread {

    
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    
    public ServerOneClient(Socket s) throws IOException {
        
        socket = s;
        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        start();
        
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();
    }
    
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import utility.Keyboard;

public class Client {
    
    private Socket socket=null;
    private ObjectOutputStream out=null;
    private ObjectInputStream in=null;
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     */
    
    Client (String address, int port) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println(socket);     
            talking();
    }
    
    private void talking() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        int decision=0;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());     // stream con richieste del client
        String menu="";
        
        do {    
            do{
            
                System.out.println("Load KNN from file [1]");
                System.out.println("Load KNN from binary file  [2]");
                System.out.println("Load KNN from database  [3]");
                decision=Keyboard.readInt();
            }while(decision <0 || decision >3);
            
            String risposta="";
            do {
                out.writeObject(decision);
                String tableName="";
                System.out.println("Table name (without estensione):");
                tableName=Keyboard.readString();
                out.writeObject(tableName);
                risposta=(String)in.readObject();
            
            }while(risposta.contains("@ERROR"));
            
            System.out.println("KNN loaded on the server");
            // predict
            String c;
            do {
                out.writeObject(4);
                boolean flag=true; //reading example
                do {
                    risposta=(String)(in.readObject());
                    if(!risposta.contains("@ENDEXAMPLE")) {
                        // sto leggendo l'esempio
                        String msg=(String)(in.readObject());
                        if(risposta.equals("@READSTRING"))  //leggo una stringa
                        {
                            System.out.println(msg);
                            out.writeObject(Keyboard.readString());
                        }
                        else //leggo un numero
                        {
                            double x=0.0;
                            do {
                                System.out.println(msg);                                
                                x=Keyboard.readDouble();
                            }
                            while(new Double(x).equals(Double.NaN));
                            out.writeObject(x);
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else flag=false;
                }while( flag);
                
                //sto leggendo  k
                risposta=(String)(in.readObject());
                int k=0;
                do {
                    System.out.print(risposta);
                    k=Keyboard.readInt();
                }while (k<1);
                out.writeObject(k);
                //aspetto la predizione 
                
                System.out.println("Prediction:"+in.readObject());
    
                    
        
                System.out.println("Vuoi ripetere predizione? Y/N");
                c=Keyboard.readString();
                
            }while (c.toLowerCase().equals("y"));   
            System.out.println("Vuoi ripetere una nuova esecuzione con un nuovo oggetto KNN? (Y/N)");
            menu=Keyboard.readString();
        }
        while(menu.toLowerCase().equals("y"));
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        InetAddress addr;
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        }
        
        Client c;
        try {
            c=new Client("localhost", 2025);
            
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        }
    }

        


}
```

Hope you can help me, for any doubt, i'm here!

Comment: ServerOneClient is not used. At all. So it doesn't matter what code you put in it.

Comment: I know.. but probably i do not understand how it should work

Comment: Use your search engine to search for "java simple multithreaded server".

Comment: sorry but i was here to learn something new, thanks to some advices given by people who has a lot experience. I would prefer this instead of searching on Google.